# Hide video of youtubeview play only audio

Tags: android, audio, video, youtube-api

Hi I'm developing an application which shows youtube videos and play them.
I don't care about the video at all I only need to play the audio of it.
I tried to hide the view,to set it's position out of the screen,to set it's height to 1 dp,everything pauses the video.
I don't know how hard is it to fetch the audio out of the video,and I would be happy to learn how to do so,but right now I prefer only to hide or show blank screen with the audio playing.
If its not possible to hide as i asked, please explain how to fetch the audio out of the video.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=fr) of the YouTube API, API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to:

- separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;
- promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;
- use the YouTube API intentionally to encourage or promote copyright infringement or the exploitation of copyright-infringing materials;

Comment: it's just for my own usage.